# How do I reverse the process of the following form element disabling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve the reverse of the following form function. This is working in the reverse to how I want it to function. I would like to have the form elements disabled by default and then enabled when the "clicker" is pressed.  I am experimenting with the following code without success.  I have no problems with the HTML, my problem is getting the script to function the way that I want it to.

SAMPLE HTML FORM ELEMENTS

```
<input type='text'></input>
<input type='text'></input>
<input type='text'></input>
<div id='clicker' style='background-color:#FF0000; height:40px; width:100px;'></div>
```

This is the JavaScript I am trying:

```
$().ready(function() {

$('#clicker').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr({
                'disabled': 'disabled'
            });
        }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you set `disabled` attribute in HTML markup by default? That's said, to enable them, it is preferred to use `prop()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `disabled` attribute from your HTML inputs, simply add the attribute as shown below:

```
<input type='text' disabled />
<input type='text' disabled />
<input type='text' disabled />
```

Your `clicker` button then will remove this attribute (See JSFiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/xredrdur/

Comment: As a side note, `input` is void element, there is no closing tag

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you also, your jsfiddle as well as @charlietfl works perfectly.  The same applies however as above when I try to run the code in a test file.  Being a novice at discussions on this forum, how do I post my current code for checking.

Comment: I now have the code working correctly, I now have to work out how to isolate the sequence to  a specific set of form elements in the overall form.  Thank you for all of the advice and help.

Comment: @Ivan - if this helped, please mark it as the answer (Tick next to the answer).  If you need help with the isolation, please post another question and I will try and help out.

Answer (score 2):

Should use `prop()` not `attr()` for `disabled`.

You can also use `prop(propertyName, fn)` to create the loop and isolate instances

```
$(function () {
    inputs_toggle_disable();//disable on page load, assumes none have disabled in markup
    $('button').click(inputs_toggle_disable);
});

function inputs_toggle_disable() {
    $('input').prop('disabled', function () {
        return !this.disabled
    });
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmp0vc20/2)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Your jsfiddle Demo works perfectly and is exactly what I am trying to do.  However when I create a small html test file with the code it will not work for me.  I am obviously missing or omitting something in the code even after cutting and pasting into my test file.

Comment: did you include jQuery.js in the file? And put it before any of this code? Use F12 in browser and look at console for errors

Comment: That did the job. I forgot to call the jquery.js in my code. Must be old age catching up. Thanks once again.

Comment: don't feel bad...my age is up there too ... am a child of the '60's